# Why my sphere texture broken? [Directx 9, c++]

Tags: c++, directx-9

I use D3DXCreateSphere() function create my sphere, and I want to get vertex position to calculate texture coordinate，but it broken!!! I need help~

1. [front side](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t34.0-12/12029011_1219815694700480_2006034957_n.jpg?oh=30c8604931688bd926374d748bd51a23&oe=5608836E&__gda__=1443473285_2bbd898375d0b07fd0b0eb62d3281f59)
2. [back side](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/v/t34.0-12/12032291_1219815698033813_1650487804_n.jpg?oh=e066d40338022bb35f15b91a68940edb&oe=5609B72D&__gda__=1443464741_b8b96b750bd7c43505234cdce9dd2fc6)

This is my struct vertex：

> struct _VERTEX {    D3DXVECTOR3 norm;   float tu;           float tv; };

This is my code：

```
LPD3DXMESH mesh;
LPD3DXMESH texMesh;

D3DXCreateSphere(pDev, 3, 20, 20, &mesh, NULL);

mesh->CloneMeshFVF(D3DXMESH_SYSTEMMEM, FVF_VERTEX, pDev, &texMesh);

mesh->Release();

_VERTEX *pVerts;
if (SUCCEEDED(texMesh->LockVertexBuffer(0, (void **)&pVerts))) {

    int numVerts = texMesh->GetNumVertices();

    for (int i = 0; i<numVerts; i++) {

        pVerts->tu = asinf(pVerts->norm.x) / D3DX_PI + 0.5f;
        pVerts->tv = asinf(pVerts->norm.y) / D3DX_PI + 0.5f;

        pVerts++;
    }

    texMesh->UnlockVertexBuffer();
}

pDev->SetTexture(0, texture);
texMesh->DrawSubset(0);
```

Comment: Why are you using Direct3D 9 which is over a decade old? D3DX is deprecated and no longer supported. In any case, you can look at the source for [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)'s ``GeometricPrimitive`` which includes a sphere.